# Promise.all inside another Promise.all seems to be exiting before its done and shows warning of not returning from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using this function to be called in another Promise.all. But I always get this warning: Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it.
Also the function deleteFutureAppointments() seems to exit from the original promise.all and starts doing other works in that promise.all chain.

```js
function deleteFutureAppointments() {
Appointment.findAll(
{ where: 
    { 
        pro_id, client_id, from_datetime_utc: { 
            $gt: new Date() 
        }
    } 
})
.then((appointments) => {
    if (!appointments) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
    }          
    const promises = appointments.map((id) => {
        const appointmentQuery = { where: { client_id } };
        const appointmentSMIQuery = { where: { appointment_id: id.get("appointment_id") } };
        return AppointmentMedia.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                removeAppointmentMedia.push(id.get("appointment_id"));
            }
            AppointmentService.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery);
        })
        .then(() => IndexAppointmentCalendar.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery))
        .then(() => Appointment.destroy(appointmentQuery));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
})
.catch((err) => {
    next(err);
});
}
```

Comment: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you aren't `return`ing the `Promise` from `AppointmentService.destroy` - might be your issue. I'd restructure as:

```js
function deleteFutureAppointments() {
  Appointment.findAll({ where: {
    pro_id, client_id,
    from_datetime_utc: { $gt: new Date() }
  } }).then(appointments => {
    return Promise.all(appointments.map(appointment => {
      var id = appointment.get("appointment_id");
      const appointmentSMIQuery = { where: {
        appointment_id: id
      } };
      return AppointmentMedia.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery).then(result => {
        if (result)
          removeAppointmentMedia.push(id);
        return AppointmentService.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery);
      })
      .then(() => IndexAppointmentCalendar.destroy(appointmentSMIQuery))
      .then(() => Appointment.destroy({ where: { client_id } }));
    }));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    next(err);
  });
}
```